# how to add a certificate to WCF ChannelFactory?

Tags: wcf, certificate, channelfactory

I need a simple WCF sample code or tutorial or a link that shows the steps on how to add a certificate to ChannelFactory?

Answer (score 7):

Does this help?

```
     // Create a proxy with the previously create binding and 
           // endpoint address
              channelFactory = 
                 new ChannelFactory<IEchoService>(
                     multipleTokensBinding, serviceAddress);
           // configure the username credentials, the client 
           // certificate and the server certificate on the channel 
           // factory 
           channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
           channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
           channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
           "CN=client.com", StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My);
              channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(
           "CN=localhost", StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My);
           client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
           Console.WriteLine("Echo service returned: {0}", 
                                           client.Echo());

           ((IChannel)client).Close();
           channelFactory.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException e)
        {
         Abort((IChannel)client, channelFactory);
         // if there is a fault then print it out
         FaultException fe = null;
         Exception tmp = e;
         while (tmp != null)
         {
            fe = tmp as FaultException;
            if (fe != null)
            {
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp.InnerException;
        }
        if (fe != null)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("The server sent back a fault: {0}", 
         fe.CreateMessageFault().Reason.GetMatchingTranslation().Text);
        }
        else
        {
         Console.WriteLine("The request failed with exception: {0}",e);
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        Abort((IChannel)client, channelFactory);
        Console.WriteLine("The request timed out");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Abort((IChannel)client, channelFactory);
          Console.WriteLine(
          "The request failed with unexpected exception: {0}", e);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate client.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: @Thanks Zedo, I appreciate your response. Any helpful link to understand the steps/code? I will try to implement this meanwhile.